# Jquery code to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to implement the following using pure javascript?

```
if ( ! $('body.posts.show').length && ! $('body.posts.edit').length && ! $('body.chunks.create').length) 
{
   // Something here
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out: your selectors are probably more specific than they should/need to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to get a single collection with all those selectors and see if it's empty.

In jQuery, you'd do this:

```
if ( ! $('body.posts.show, body.posts.edit, body.chunks.create').length )
```

The vanilla Javascript approach isn't much more difficult:

```
if (!document.querySelector('body.posts.show, body.posts.edit, body.chunks.create')) {
```

See the [MDN documentation for `document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

Comment: What is the browser support

Comment: @Anam See the bottom of the page I link. It works in any version of Chrome, FF 3.5+, IE 8+. If you need to support IE <8, I suggest you use a library to help you. jQuery, perhaps!

Comment: nice one!! I missed to notice single line way of accessing the inner elements.  But `querySelector` will only the first occurrence of the element, so it has to be `querySelectorAll` in order to fetch multiple elements.

Comment: @Praveen But we're checking to find if there are *no* elements. So we don't care if there's more than one: if we've found one, we don't need to keep checking. Also, you're *very* unlikely to have more than one `body` element in a page!

Comment: `But we're checking to find if there are no elements` valid point :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! I would suggest to go with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) methods.

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var posts = body.querySelector('posts');
var chunks = body.querySelector('chunks');
var show = posts.querySelectorAll('show');
var edits = posts.querySelectorAll('edit');
var create = chunks..querySelectorAll('create');

if ( !show.length && !edit.length && !create.length) {
 // Something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript `document.querySelectorAll('')`! try this

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll('body.posts.show').length && !document.querySelectorAll('body.posts.edit').length && !document.querySelectorAll('body.chunks.create').length) 
{
  // Something here
}
```

even better would be

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll('body.posts.show, body.posts.edit, body.chunks.create').length) 
{
  // Something here
}
```